# OpenCV Mat format

Tags: c++, opencv

read the image in

`Mat img=imread("i000qa-fn.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);`

try to find objects...

`faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(img,cascade, storage, 1.2, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, Size(0, 0));`

and walla...

`OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /media/Data/sdks/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482`

when I do imshow, the image is there as it should be.

Comment: The documentation for cvHaarDetectObjects says image is a "Matrix of the type CV_8U containing an image where objects are detected". I think the error is telling you your `img` isn't CV_8U.

Comment: made sure to call img->convertTo(temp, CV_8U,1./255,0); right before the function and no it still doesnt work...

Comment: It infact was both of your solutions, apparantly you have to convert to 8U then create the IplImage and pass that to HDO

Comment: no, in C++ one has to find the proper function(ality) that does not begin with "cv".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Andrey (@AndreyKamaev), you need a different function instead:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
using namespace cv;

Mat img = imread(img_path);
CascadeClassifier haar_cascade.load(path);

vector<Rect> detection_rois;
haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, detection_rois, 1.2, 2, 
                                  0|CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);
```

That is how Haar detector is used in C++ since Opencv 2.3.1 that is since Aug. 2011. [Also let me attach a documentation.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html)

Here is a proof, below. :) I did a Haar_detector wrapper around this cv::CascadeClassifier -- which *is* really an Adaboost cascade classifier with Haar-like features, therefore the name.

[image: The proof]

Comment: the cascade classifier code was not ported to 2.x c++ library, you have to use cv...

Comment: well, I am using exactly this code in my OpenCV 2.4.2 C++ program. And I have also used it OpenCV 2.3.1. Let me put there the necessary include, too, and you'll see.

Comment: Can you please let me know when you've tried my code once again like that?

Comment: Yes, it is not that old in Opencv 2.x, it is only here since Aug 2011, in version OpenCV 2.3.1, but I think I earned the removal of the down-vote, at least. :)

Answer (score 3):

`cvHaarDetectObjects` expects `IplImage` or `CvMat` but you are passing `cv::Mat` object.

So you need a conversion like this:

```
IplImage img1 = img;
faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(&img1, cascade, storage, 1.2, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, Size(0, 0));
```

Comment: if i do that i get: OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat

Comment: what if replace `IplImage` with `CvMat`?

Comment: same result, does one have to also copy the data to the new IplImage object?